# Unity's gameObject.Findgameobjectswithtag not appearing in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently trying to make my first game using unity and I need to find a tagged trigger in order to make the player score increase when they pass through a goal. but when I try to use the `.Findgameobjectswithtag` command, it won't show up as an allowable command and if I try to run it, nothing happens. does anyone know if there is a reason for this or even an alternative method.

I have tried to run it anyways, but it wont let me because it causes an error. Here is the error I get:

> Error CS1061
> 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'findgameobjectwithtag' and no accessible extension method 'findgameobjectwithtag' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone know if there is a reason for this or even an alternative method ?

Comment: im also getting this warning if it helps (Warning CS8032: An instance of analyzer Unity.MonoScriptGenerator.MonoScriptInfoGenerator cannot be created from C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.4f1\Editor\Data\Tools\Unity.SourceGenerators\Unity.SourceGenerators.dll: Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..))

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) for information and an example on the usage of `FindGameObjectsWithTag`. One thing I would note that the function is a static function, and it's possible you are trying to call it from an instance of `GameObject`, which wouldn't work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`GameObject` doesn't have a method named `Findgameobjectswithtag`. The method you're looking for is called `FindGameObjectsWithTag`. C# methods use upper camelcase, so the first letter of each word is capitalized. Ex: `MyMethod`, not `Mymethod` or `myMethod`.